# WP7 - Memory & LINQ Database querys

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, memory

Got a query that changes a boolean value in the DB.

```
    private void optFavorit_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var opt_query = (from q in db.TableBarcode where q.IdBarcode == selectedItem select q).First();
        Database.Barcode currentBarcode = new Database.Barcode();

        if (opt_query.Favorit == true) 
        {
            currentBarcode.Update(selectedItem, false, opt_query.Scanned, opt_query.Titel, opt_query.Inhalt);
            optFavorit.Content = "Fav. adden";
        }
        else if (opt_query.Favorit == false)
        {
            currentBarcode.Update(selectedItem, true, opt_query.Scanned, opt_query.Titel, opt_query.Inhalt);
            optFavorit.Content = "Fav. entf."; 
        }
    }
```

and it works, the correct results are shown & updated on every other page EXCEPT the XAML page where I've executed the query. Also, if I return to the page where I excuted the query it won't allow me to change the value again.

Seems like a problem with the memory. If I restart the complete App, the correct result is also shown on the page where I've executed the query but again I only can execute the query 1x per object and from here on i'm caught again in the loop.

Any idea? Help would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT:

Alright found a solution even if I don't understand what's the big difference.

```
        private void optFavorit_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Komischer weise sind 2 Abfragen nötig! Nicht opt_query.Favorit im if verwenden!
        var opt_query = (from q in db.TableBarcode where q.IdBarcode == selectedItem select q).First();
        var isFavo = (from q in db.TableBarcode where q.IdBarcode == selectedItem select q.Favorit).First();
        Database.Barcode currentBarcode = new Database.Barcode();

        if (isFavo == true) 
        {
            currentBarcode.Update(selectedItem, false, opt_query.Scanned, opt_query.Titel, opt_query.Inhalt);
        }
        else if (isFavo == false)
        {
            currentBarcode.Update(selectedItem, true, opt_query.Scanned, opt_query.Titel, opt_query.Inhalt);
        }
    }
```

Maybe someone can explain me but atleast it works now :)